# LazyInitializationException in jsf project

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, jpa

I am facing the LazyInitializationException in my jsf project.
and I also know that fetch = FetchType.EAGER is not the right way to solve my problem.
I got some idea from this post http://blog.gmorales.net/2012/03/how-to-solve-orghibernatelazyinitializa.html that there is a solution using OpenSessionInViewFilter:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilterr</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

so in other word, I have to implement the Spring framework for my project?
I want to know is there a way that JSF provided to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you using plain Hibernate or JPA?

Comment: JPA with hibernate provider.

Comment: JSF doesn't offer anything to solve this "problem". It's just a component based MVC framework, not an object relational mapper. Just rewrite your JPA code in such way that it doesn't lazily fetch when the current request really needs the whole graph.